# Foundry Fuzzing How to increase the runs to be more than default 256

Tags: solidity, testing, foundry, fuzz-test

I am testing the Foundry Fuzzing feature. Therefore I created this simple contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Vault {
bool public s_locked;
uint private s_password;

constructor(uint password) {
    s_locked = true;
    s_password = password;
}

function unlock(uint password) external {
    if (s_password == password) {
        s_locked = false;
    }
}
}
```

And here its test:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import "forge-std/Test.sol";
import "forge-std/console.sol";
import "../src/Vault.sol";

contract VaultFuzzTest is Test {

Vault public vault;

function setUp() public {
    vault = new Vault(5);
}

function testFuzz_password(uint x) public {
  vault.unlock(x);
  assertEq(vault.s_locked(), true);
}
}
```

When I run it, the test is passing successfully, however it shouldn't when the password is equal to 5.
See output:

```
Test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 10.94ms
  Ran 1 test suites: 1 tests passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped (1 total tests)
```

That is why I was wondering, is Foundry just trying random 256 values (I assume all 256 values are big numbers) and if it doesn't find 5 among them, it just returns success. If so, is there a way I can fuzz my contract with more than 256 values, so eventually I get my test fail?

What else I have tried: adding   `vm.assume(x<10);`

```
function testFuzz_password(uint x) public {
  vm.assume(x<10);
  vault.unlock(x);
  assertEq(vault.s_locked(), true);
}
```

Now when I run my test it fails:

```
Failing tests:
Encountered 1 failing test in test/Vault.t.sol:VaultFuzzTest
[FAIL. Reason: Assertion failed. Counterexamplecalldata=0x0ce2d6010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005, args=[5]] testFuzz_password(uint256) (runs: 6, μ: 13283, ~: 13283)

  Encountered a total of 1 failing tests, 0 tests succeeded
```

When I put a constraint where the password is assumed to be <10, then the fuzzing works as expected and throws an error.

Therefore I wanted to ask someone with more experience with Foundry to explain me how it works and should I increase the runs in order to achieve the same behaviour but without using vm.assume(x<10);

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found how to increase fuzz runs:
Inside the foundry.toml
Add this

```
[fuzz]
runs = 1000000
```

But I don't know whether that is correct solution.

Comment: This is. The fuzzer tries semi-random variables as input, sort of like a brute-force attempting to crack the code. So the more runs, the better.